# É possível fazer selecionar arquivo input[file] WebBrowser VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, navegador-de-internet

estou fazendo uma aplicação onde será necessário selecionar uma imagem.
assim ficará automático, e depois ele irá publicar.

é possível de alguma maneira selecionar essa imagem, ou até mesmo fazer um upload, aplicar no value....

utilizando o webbrowser.

[image: Este será campo de upload, tenho que colocar uma imagem nele.]

Este será campo de upload, tenho que colocar uma imagem nele.

**@EDIT@**

Programa que estou fazendo ele faz postagem na minha fãn page do facebook de fotos, ou seja, ele clica em fotos, e terá que colocar a foto.

assim, carrega e ele clica em publicar automaticamente.

Achei uma opção, até agora.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("" & imgDir & "")
SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
```

Comment: Dê mais detalhes, coloque o que fez. Não dá para saber o que quer e qual seu problema só com isto.

Comment: @bigown atualizei tópico com mais informações.